# Displaying a Decimal Field as a Slider in Django

Tags: django

I have defined a Decimal Field in my Forms.py

```
class Slider(forms.Form):
     slider_form= forms.DecimalField(min_value=0.0, max_value=1.0, initial = 0.5, 
                                     required=True, label=False, decimal_places=1,
                                     widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'step': "0.1"}))
```

Is there a good way to convert the display to a slider in Django?

Would it be better to attack this on the front-end instead using Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that this way:

```
class Slider(forms.Form):
    slider_form = forms.DecimalField(
        required=True, 
        label=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'step': '0.1', 
                'type': 'range', 
                'value': '0.5', 
                'min': '0.1', 
                'max': '1'
            }
        )
    )
```

This will render a slider.

[image]